# How to force an edit to readonly property in c# for unit testing

Tags: c#, properties

I have the following property in my class.

```
public bool IsUser
{
    get
    {
        return true; 
    }           
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this one where I have to make `IsUser` as false.

I am trying to avoid changes in the original property. Is it possible to change just in the unit test.

Comment: When you say you don't want to change the property, do you mean you don't want to edit the code at all?  Or just change the functionality of the property?

Comment: If the value never changes to false, then why need test **true**?

Comment: Why do you need to test a condition that can never occur? If IsUser is always true who cares what happens if it is false?

Comment: just to increase some code coverage, I need to set it as false. I was just wondering if that could be possible.

Comment: as I said you cannot do that without proper variable field declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you posted not support any assign operation at all
because you actualy did not store any information you just return logical constant. To support assign operation you must use some class field explicitly as I posted in first example of implicitly - in second.

You may make `set` method of property protected, than derive test class or mock class with public `IsUser` property setter in you test assembly from class you want to test.

```
public bool IsUser 
{    
     protected set
     {
           _someMemberVariable = value;
     }
     get 
     { 
           return _someMemberVariable; 
     }           
}
```

or just

```
public bool IsUser 
{    
     protected set;
     get;         
}
```

This snippet displays property wich can be read from any classes but, can be assigned only from itself or derived types.

`_someMemberVariable` in this case must be private class field.

Comment: thanks this one worked the way I wanted, but never thanked you for it.
Thanks again :)